# Getting json latitude and longitude in android map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

Am working with map here am getting latitude , longitude and other details from json web service successfully but while displaying in map only one marker is displaying other latitude , longitude and markers are not displaying in map

```
class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading locations...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        e = JSONfunctions
          .getJSONfromURL("http://beauty.ls.com/webservices/MapStores.php?client_id=1");
        Log.d("jsonobject", String.valueOf(e));


        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            Log.d("second", "");
            jsonarray = e.getJSONArray("mapstores");
            Log.d("three","");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                e = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                 store_lat = e.getString("store_latitude");
                 store_long = e.getString("store_longitude");
                 store_id = e.getString("store_id");
                 store_name = e.getString("store_name");
                 store_address = e.getString("store_address");
                 store_city = e.getString("store_city");
                 store_phone = e.getString("store_phone");
                 store_email = e.getString("store_email");
                Log.d("latitude",store_lat);
                Log.d("longitude",store_long);

                lat1 = Double.parseDouble(store_lat);
                lng1 = Double.parseDouble(store_long);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat1, lng1))
                    .title(e.getString("store_id")));

    }
}
```

I dont know where should i make change please help me

Comment: have you tried my solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this way:

What is wrong with your code: You are adding single lat long on `PostExecute()` instead of adding code for all `LatLng` in for loop.

```
class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading locations...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        e = JSONfunctions
          .getJSONfromURL("http://beauty.ls.com/webservices/MapStores.php?client_id=1");
        Log.d("jsonobject", String.valueOf(e));
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            Log.d("second", "");
            jsonarray = e.getJSONArray("mapstores");
            Log.d("three","");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                e = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                 store_lat = e.getString("store_latitude");
                 store_long = e.getString("store_longitude");
                 store_id = e.getString("store_id");
                 store_name = e.getString("store_name");
                 store_address = e.getString("store_address");
                 store_city = e.getString("store_city");
                 store_phone = e.getString("store_phone");
                 store_email = e.getString("store_email");
                Log.d("latitude",store_lat);
                Log.d("longitude",store_long);

                lat1 = Double.parseDouble(store_lat);
                lng1 = Double.parseDouble(store_long);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat1, lng1))
                    .title(e.getString("store_id")));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok what is JSONfunctions in your code?

Anyways what you want to do is , use the jsonArray which has lat long values from the api response in post execute method and traverse till the end of the array. Now **for each iteration, call addMarker on the map** with the lat long value for that iteration.

This way ensures that you are adding different markers,for corresponding Latitude and Longitude.

What you are currently doing is adding the marker only once on the map although you are getting all the lat long values from the response.

Here is the snippet for this:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        e = JSONfunctions
          .getJSONfromURL("http://beauty.ls.com/webservices/MapStores.php?client_id=1");
        Log.d("jsonobject", String.valueOf(e));
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            Log.d("second", "");
            jsonarray = e.getJSONArray("mapstores");
            Log.d("three","");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                e = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                 store_lat = e.getString("store_latitude");
                 store_long = e.getString("store_longitude");
                 store_id = e.getString("store_id");
                 store_name = e.getString("store_name");
                 store_address = e.getString("store_address");
                 store_city = e.getString("store_city");
                 store_phone = e.getString("store_phone");
                 store_email = e.getString("store_email");
                Log.d("latitude",store_lat);
                Log.d("longitude",store_long);

                lat1 = Double.parseDouble(store_lat);
                lng1 = Double.parseDouble(store_long);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat1, lng1))
                    .title(e.getString("store_id")));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Well while I was typing, @hiren has already given the answer. :P 
Hope you will get what you require.